# Rails Capistrano Authentication failed error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I am attempting to deploy my Rails 4 application using Capistrano 3.4, but continuously get an authentication failed error. I just don't understand where I am supposed to set the password for the Git repo.

Here is my error message when running the command `cap production deploy --trace`:

```
** Execute git:check
INFO [d5512476] Running /usr/bin/env git ls-remote --heads https://xxx@bitbucket.org/xxx/myapp.git as xxx@162.242.219.184
DEBUG [d5512476] Command: ( GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/xxx/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git ls-remote --heads https://xxx@bitbucket.org/xxx/myapp.git )
DEBUG [d5512476]        fatal: Authentication failed
DEBUG [d5512476]
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as xxx@162.242.219.184: git exit status: 128
git stdout: fatal: Authentication failed
git stderr: Nothing written
/home/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:16:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in execute'
/home/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
SSHKit::Command::Failed: git exit status: 128
git stdout: fatal: Authentication failed
git stderr: Nothing written
/home/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/command.rb:95:in `exit_status='
/home/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:179:in `block in _execute'
/home/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:133:in `tap'
/home/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:133:in `_execute'
/home/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:66:in `execute'
/home/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/capistrano-3.4.0/lib/capistrano/git.rb:11:in `git'
/home/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/capistrano-3.4.0/lib/capistrano/git.rb:21:in `check'
/home/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/capistrano-3.4.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/git.rake:28:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:85:in `with'
/home/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/capistrano-3.4.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/git.rake:27:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `instance_exec'
/home/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `run'
/home/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/sshkit-1.7.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
Tasks: TOP => git:check
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as xxx@162.242.219.184: git exit status: 128
git stdout: fatal: Authentication failed
git stderr: Nothing written
** Invoke deploy:failed (first_time)
** Execute deploy:failed
```

`deploy.rb`

```
lock '3.4.0'

set :application, 'xxx'
set :repo_url, 'https://xxx@bitbucket.org/xxx/myapp.git'
set :deploy_to, 'home/xxx/Sites/myapp'
set :scm, :git
set :format, :pretty
set :pty, true
```

`deploy/production.rb`

```
server '123.45.678.90', user: 'xxx', roles: %w{web app}
role :app, %w{xxx@123.45.678.90}
role :web, %w{xxx@123.45.678.90}
role :db,  %w{xxx@123.45.678.90}
```

Now I have tried to fiddle around with the parameters in `production.rb`, but I keep getting syntax errors.

```
# Custom SSH Options
# ==================
# You may pass any option but keep in mind that net/ssh understands a
# limited set of options, consult the Net::SSH documentation.
# http://net-ssh.github.io/net-ssh/classes/Net/SSH.html#method-c-start
#
# Global options
# --------------
#  set :ssh_options, {
#    keys: %w(/home/rlisowski/.ssh/id_rsa),
#    forward_agent: false,
#    auth_methods: %w(password)
#  }
#
# The server-based syntax can be used to override options:
# ------------------------------------
# server '123.45.678.90',
#   user: 'defined_user',
#   roles: %w{web app},
#   password: 'mypassword'
#   ssh_options: {
#     user: 'user',
#     keys: %w(/home/user_name/.ssh/id_rsa),
#     forward_agent: false,
#     auth_methods: %w(publickey password)
#   }
```

Comment: You should generate an SSH key pair on your sever. Then, add the public key as a deploy ket to your git repo in bitbucket. After that you should be able to download your git repo without entering a password.

Comment: Visit this tutorial, I know it is made for webfaction hosting, but it applies to other servers as well https://docs.webfaction.com/software/rails.html#deploying-a-ruby-on-rails-application-with-capistrano

Comment: @joshua.paling This is the solution. Thank you. If you'd like you can post your comment as an answer so I can mark it correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should generate an SSH key pair on your sever. Then, add the public key as a deploy ket to your git repo in bitbucket. After that you should be able to download your git repo without entering a password

Answer (score 0):

Deploy keys are usually for automated deployments, when you absolutely have to leave the key on server, and in case it gets compromised - someone also can access your repo.

Other method to authenticate server to access git is to use ssh agent forwarding, this way is a bit safer in this respect.

Run `ssh-add` to add your current ssh keys to agent session and try again, also capistrano should have ssh agent forwarding enabled, in 3 it's enabled by default, but just in case:

```
set :ssh_options, { forward_agent: true }
```